# Stripping formatting tags from RTF using C

Tags: objective-c, c, parsing, converters, rtf

I have an RTF string, that may (or may not) be prematurely truncated.  I want to be able to strip all the formatting tags from the RTF string leaving only the readable text behind.
I've seen some regex which claims to be able to do the job - but this is no good for me.  Ideally, I need the code to be in pure, portable, C - but, failing that, Objective C will do.
Please note the 'prematurely truncated' clause - the following code will not work because it returns nil for truncated RTF.

```
    +(NSString*)RTFAsPlainText:(NSData*)RTFSource
    {
        NSAttributedString* rtfString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF: RTFSource documentAttributes:nil];  
        return [rtfString string];
    }
```

Does anyone know of a library that can perform this function?  As I say, it needs to be able to work whether or not the RTF string is complete.

Comment: I don't, but if you look at the RTF formatting you can probably make a quick regex to do most of it.

Comment: As I say, I've seen some regex that claims to be able to do the job - albeit imperfectly.  I need a slightly better solution.  I tried using some of the Regex, from within Objective-C (I'd prefer nice clean C, but I don't know of a way to do Regex in C), but Objc is very picky about the Regex standards that it supports (no * and limited +), so none of the Regexes worked. That's why I want something in C (or, at a pinch Objective C)